# Radius function from length of curve

Tags: plane-curves

I have the following function definition for the length of a curve: 
$$
l(\theta) = {K_0 \times \sin(\theta) \over \cos(\theta) + K_1}
\\ 0 \le \theta \lt \frac \pi 2
\\ K_0, K_1 \ge 0
$$
I would like a function which describes the radius of curve so I can graph it.

(First question / post, so moderators please feel free to modify as necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, $l(\theta)$ expresses the length of the curve from its initial point to the point with polar angle $\theta$. Since the initial point is at $\theta=0$, the standard formula for length in polar coordinates gives 
$$
l(\theta)= \int_0^\theta \sqrt{r'(t)^2+r(t)^2}\,dt 
\tag1 $$
Differentiating both sides and squaring, we obtain a differential equation for $r$: 
$$
r'(\theta)^2+r(\theta)^2 = (l\,'(\theta))^2   
\tag2 $$
where the function $(l'(\theta))^2$ is known. This is a nonlinear ODE with no obvious (to me) simplifications. I think numerical or approximate solutions are necessary here.

For example, I took $K_0=K_1=1$, which simplifies a lot: $l\,'(\theta)=1/(1+\cos\theta)$. Then outsourced the job to Maple:

```
sol:=dsolve([diff(r(theta),theta)= sqrt(ls-r(theta)^2), r(0)=0],numeric, range=0..Pi/2);
odeplot(sol, [r(theta)*cos(theta),r(theta)*sin(theta)],thickness=3);
```

[image: plot of solution]

With these constants $r(\theta)$ is pretty close to $\theta/2$, so the curve looks like an Archimedean spiral.

Comment: @user53153 Hi, I'm having a problem duplicating your result, perhaps because I haven't used my ODE solver in along while. In the meantime, I would ask if you did a parity check on this numerical result. To wit, did you compare the curvature calculated from $r$ and $\theta$ with the original $l(\theta)$. I though your approach to creating the DE was very clever.